# Find a matching string and then + 1 to element

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops, csv

I'm trying to make a loop to go through a 2 dimensional list, if the loop finds the matching string that is in the first element then it adds +1 to the second element of the list.

An example of the list:

`[[mike, 0], [john, 2], [henry, 0], [sam, 1]]`

If the required search was for John this would happen:

`[[mike, 0], [john, 3], [henry, 0], [sam, 1]]`

And then for Mike:

`[[mike, 1], [john, 3], [henry, 0], [sam, 1]]`

In the below scenario 'name' is the string getting brought in that needs to be found.

I'm also pulling the list of names in from a CSV file and then writing the updated list back.

I can't seem to get this to work, and the error that is coming back to me is

> 'TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list''

```
def count(name):
    with open('nameList.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        nameList = list(reader)
    for x in range(len(nameList)):
        if nameList[x][0] == name:
            print(nameList== name)
            nameList[1] = nameList[1] + 1
    with open("nameList.csv", "w", newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        for i in nameList:
            writer.writerow(i)
```

Any ideas about how to get this working?  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the original problem you are trying to solve is to get the counts of the names.

If that's the case, then it can be accomplished much more easily using `Counter` from Python's `collections` module.

```
from collections import Counter

cnt = Counter()
with open("nameList.csv", 'r') as f:
    rd = csv.reader(f)
    cnt = Counter(r[0] for r in rd)

print(cnt)
```

`cnt` will be dict-like object (you can use it just like any other dictionary) where the keys are the names from the CSV and the values are the counts. So, it might look something like this:

```
{'john': 3, 'mike': 1, 'sam': 1}
```

Now suppose you have another CSV with names and you want to find the count of each name in both the files. You can do this just as easily, by updating `cnt`:

```
with open("nameList2.csv", 'r') as f:
    rd2 = csv.reader(f)
    cnt.update(r[0] for r in rd2)
```

You avoid counting from scratch *and* the code is way more sexy! Simple and elegant!

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response !  I just gave that a quick run, I was only hoping to add +1 to the specific name that is brought through into the function each time, as opposed to all of the names.  Great thing you showed me however, honestly has solved a completely different problem that I was trying to figure out! Thanks

Comment: I have added some information that might be helpful to you

Comment: Amazing all sorted now, thanks for taking the time to be so helpful!

Comment: Glad to be of service. :)

Answer (score 0):

The one thing that stands out is this line:

```
 nameList[1] = nameList[1] + 1
```

`nameList[1]` is the second inner list in your main list. I think you probably meant `nameList[x][1]`:

```
nameList[x][1] = nameList[x][1] + 1
```

Comment: I have just edited my code to do this, however it is returning this 'TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list'  which, I feel may be similar to the original issue?  Thanks !

Comment: What is contained within nameList exactly? In my test I used `nameList = [['mike', 0], ['john', 2], ['henry', 0], ['sam', 1]]`, and when I try my suggested fix it worked. Anyway sounds like nisemonoxide has provided you with a much more succinct way of getting the data you need, and I'd recommend that over what I've suggested.